# Installing Octave-4.0.0 on CentOS yields QtOpenGL linking error

Tags: compile, libraries, qt, octave, qt4

I am in the process of trying to install Octave-4.0.0 on a CentOS 6 cluster.  Octave has 20+ dependencies, and it is unclear which versions of each dependency to use.  Since `yum` only has Octave-3.4.3, I installed Octave-3.4.3 from `yum` with the hope that it would get me the majority of dependencies right. I also had to install (via `yum`)

```
arpack-devel-3.1.3-1.el6.x86_64
fltk-devel-1.1.10-1.el6.x86_64
gl2ps-devel-1.3.5-1.el6.x86_64
glpk-devel-4.40-1.1.el6.x86_64
qhull-devel-2003.1-14.el6.x86_64
qrupdate-devel-1.1.2-1.el6.x86_64
qscintilla-devel-2.4-1.el6.x86_64
suitesparse-devel-3.4.0-9.el6.x86_64
```

and from source

```
pcre-8.36
```

I run auto config :

```
./configure JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.79.x86_64/"  CPPFLAGS="-I/home/path/to/user/local/include"  --prefix=/home/path/to/user/local/  --with-blas=/usr/lib64/atlas/libf77blas.so.3 --with-lapack=/usr/lib64/atlas/liblapack.so.3
```

It seems to find things fine and then when I run `make` it takes about 30minutes to compile and then fails with :

```
.
.
.
make[2]: Entering directory /gpfs0/home/path/to/user/local/src/octave-4.0.0/src'
CXX      octave_gui-main-gui.o
CXXLD    octave-gui
/usr/lib64/libQtOpenGL.so.4: undefined reference to 'QWidgetPrivate::checkWindowRole()'`
/usr/lib64/libQtOpenGL.so.4: undefined reference to 'QPaintEngineEx::drawPixmaps(QDrawPixmaps::Data const*, int, QPixmap const&, QFlags<QDrawPixmaps::DrawingHint>)'
/usr/lib64/libQtOpenGL.so.4: undefined reference to 'QTextureGlyphCache::populate(QTextItemInt const&, QVarLengthArray<unsigned int, 256> const&, QVarLengthArray<QFixedPoint, 256> const&)'
/usr/lib64/libQtNetwork.so.4: undefined reference to 'QObjectPrivate::checkWindowRole()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [octave-gui] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/gpfs0/home/path/to/user/local/src/octave-4.0.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/gpfs0/home/path/to/user/local/src/octave-4.0.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

In the Makefile generated by auto conf it appears that it should be linking to the Qt libraries correctly, i.e.

```
.
.
.
QT_CFLAGS = -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/Q     tOpenGL
QT_CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/usr/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/QtOpenGL
QT_LDFLAGS =
QT_LIBS = -lQtNetwork -lQtOpenGL -lQtGui -lQtCore   -lqscintilla2
.
.
.
```

In /usr/lib64/ I checked the contents of the Qt libraries

```
$ for i in *Qt*.so.4.6.2; do echo $i; nm -C -D $i | grep -i checkWindowRole; done
libQt3Support.so.4.6.2
                 U QObjectPrivate::checkWindowRole()
                 U QWidgetPrivate::checkWindowRole()
libQtAssistantClient.so.4.6.2
libQtCLucene.so.4.6.2
libQtCore.so.4.6.2
00000000001657b0 T QObjectPrivate::checkWindowRole()
libQtDBus.so.4.6.2
                 U QObjectPrivate::checkWindowRole()
libQtDesignerComponents.so.4.6.2
libQtDesigner.so.4.6.2
libQtGui.so.4.6.2
                 U QObjectPrivate::checkWindowRole()
00000000002388f0 T QWidgetPrivate::checkWindowRole()
libQtHelp.so.4.6.2
libQtMultimedia.so.4.6.2
                 U QObjectPrivate::checkWindowRole()
libQtNetwork.so.4.6.2
                 U QObjectPrivate::checkWindowRole()
libQtOpenGL.so.4.6.2
                 U QObjectPrivate::checkWindowRole()
                 U QWidgetPrivate::checkWindowRole()
libQtScript.so.4.6.2
                 U QObjectPrivate::checkWindowRole()
libQtScriptTools.so.4.6.2
                 U QObjectPrivate::checkWindowRole()
                 U QWidgetPrivate::checkWindowRole()
libQtSql.so.4.6.2
                 U QObjectPrivate::checkWindowRole()
libQtSvg.so.4.6.2
                 U QObjectPrivate::checkWindowRole()
                 U QWidgetPrivate::checkWindowRole()
libQtTest.so.4.6.2
libQtXmlPatterns.so.4.6.2
                 U QObjectPrivate::checkWindowRole()
libQtXml.so.4.6.2
```

And it appears that `QWidgetPrivate::checkWindowRole()` is declared (if I'm interpreting `nm` correctly?) within `libQtGui.so.4.6.2`.  This library is already linked to (see above)

QUESTION : How do I fix this issue and get `libQtOpenGL` to see the correct libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I have a piece of software that I installed locally on my user space and it installed some libraries in `~/local/lib`.  Within that directory, the software had installed `libQtCore.so.4` and `libQtGui.so.4`.  This were the only Qt related libraries installed here.  Likewise, I had set

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/path/to/user/local/lib
```

This meant that the linker found these libraries before the ones located in `/usr/lib64`.  Changing $LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that it no longer points to `~/local/lib`, let the linker do its job and solved my problem.